# Alternative way to identify messages in Gmail Inbox

Tags: class, google-apps-script, gmail

I'm currently using var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Delete Me");

to identify threads in Gmail Inbox that I want delete if they are of a certain age.  The method I am using depends on a filter being set for messages as "Delete Me" and I'm wondering if I could instead list the senders I'd like to delete from in my script directly.

Thanks,

Comment: It's probably better, for performance issues, to have a filter in your gmail that applies this label (verifying senders, etc), than to implement this logic inside your script. This will also give your more flexibility, since you'll be able to easily make exceptions (manually adding or removing threads to this label).

Answer (score 0):

Although, I agree with what Henrique said, however, if you MUST do the filtering and deleting of threads from your script, one way of doing it is to use the [search query](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String,Integer,Integer)) function and deleting all the threads that appear as a result of that query.

For searching by user:
`var threads = GmailApp.search('from:username@mail.com', 10, 10);`

For searching by date:
`var threads = GmailApp.search('before:04/05/2015', 10, 10);`

Would then pass `threads` through my delete function.

**EDIT:**

If you want the date to be calculated based on the current date, you could do something like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 20);
var searchTxt = "before:"+d;
var threads = GmailApp.search(searchTxt, 10, 10);
```